# FCM - Xamarin Class not found on service

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm having a problem with FCM, the app is not able to find the firebaseInstanceIdService and firebaseMessagingService, for more details, this is the exception:

```
    [AndroidRuntime] FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    [AndroidRuntime] Process: com.tracker.test, PID: 13287
    [AndroidRuntime] java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.tracker.test.MyFirebaseInstanceIdService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.tracker.test.MyFirebaseInstanceIdService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.tracker.test-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.tracker.test-1/lib/arm, /system/fake-libs, /data/app/com.tracker.test-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/vendor/lib, /product/lib]]
    [AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3313)
    [AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap5(ActivityThread.java)
    [AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1659)
    [AndroidRuntime]    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    [AndroidRuntime]    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
    [AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6524)
    [AndroidRuntime]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    [AndroidRuntime]    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:941)
    [AndroidRuntime]    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:831)
    [AndroidRuntime] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.tracker.test.MyFirebaseInstanceIdService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.tracker.test-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.tracker.test-1/lib/arm, /system/fake-libs, /data/app/com.tracker.test-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/vendor/lib, /product/lib]]
    [AndroidRuntime]    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    [AndroidRuntime]    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
    [AndroidRuntime]    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    [AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3310)
    [AndroidRuntime]    ... 8 more
    [Process] Sending signal. PID: 13287 SIG: 9
```

The AndroidManifest looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.tracker.test">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<application android:label="test">
    <service android:name="MyFirebaseInstanceIdService" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="MyFirebaseMessagingService" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>

    </manifest>
```

I've tried adding a "." before the MyFirebaseInstanceIdService and MyFirebaseMessagingService.

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Media;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using Firebase.Messaging;

namespace test2.Droid
{
    [Service]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
{
    const string TAG = "MyFirebaseMessagingService";

    public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
    {
        Android.Util.Log.Debug(TAG, "From: " + message.From);
        Android.Util.Log.Debug(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + message.GetNotification().Body);
    }

    void SendNotification(string messageBody)
    {
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

        var defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Notification);
        var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            //.SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
            .SetContentTitle("FCM Message")
            .SetContentText(messageBody)
            .SetAutoCancel(true)
            .SetSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        var notificationManager = NotificationManager.FromContext(this);

        notificationManager.Notify(0, notificationBuilder.Build());
    }
}
```

}

and MyFirebaseInstanceIdService

```
namespace test2.Droid
{
[Service]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" })]
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIdService : FirebaseInstanceIdService
{
    const string TAG = "MyFirebaseInstanceIdService";
    public override void OnTokenRefresh()
    {
        var refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;
        Log.Debug(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
    }
}
```

Any help?

Thank You!

Comment: Two questions - one, do you have the classes MyFirebaseInstanceIdService and MyFirebaseMessagingService? And two, if you do have them did you try adding their fully qualified package names in the manifest? (e.g. `<service android:name="com.tracker.test.MyFirebaseInstanceIdService"`)

Comment: Yes and yes, I've tried adding the complete package name

Comment: In my manifest file I only have the two receivers, and it is working. Did you try removing the two services from the manifest file (but still retain them in the directory) and just leave the receivers and try it again.

Comment: I commented the services lines but the message is not received, something is missing. How I tell when a message is sent to call the "MyFirebaseMessagingService" method?

Comment: Can you post your codes for MyFirebaseInstanceIdService and MyFirebaseMessagingService? Did you double check if you provided the correct Firebase server key and end-points to the notification hub? (e.g. Azure)

Comment: I've updated the post with the services code.

Comment: I think the codes are pretty much correct. The message is not received from Firebase or from the notification hub you are using? And what notification hub are you using? Azure?

Comment: when I sent a message from firebase (using the firebase console), the app crashes with the exception at the top of the page. I'm kind of lost now, don't know what other thing to try :/

Comment: Did you download the google-services.json from your firebase project and put it in the Android project of your Xamarin solution? And can you also edit your post with the new exception that you are getting.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? I had the same stack trace and was able to resolve it by a clean + rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

For your `FirebaseMessagingService` subclass, add the class attributes `Service` and `IntentFilter`:

Example:

```
[Service]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
{
  ~~~~
}
```

For your `FirebaseInstanceIdService` subclass add the same but with the different intent filter:

```
[Service]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" })]
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIdService : FirebaseInstanceIdService
{
  ~~~
}
```

In your manifest, add Firebase receivers ***within*** your application tag:

```
<application ...... >
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</applcication>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem and resolve by enable multidex,

1. Add following dependency in app gradle file
   `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'`

```
defaultConfig {
 multiDexEnabled true
}
```

2. Your application class need to extends `MultiDexApplication`